# Given a normal variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and another variable $Y|X \sim N(f(X),g(X))$, under what conditions is $Y$ normal?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

Given a normal variable $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma)$ and another variable $Y|X \sim N(f(X),g(X))$, under what conditions is $Y$ normal?

I believe that $g(X)$ has to be constant and $f(X)$ has to be a linear function $a+bX$. I am struggling to prove it.
$$
\Phi_Y(t)=\mathbb{E}[e^{\mathbf{i}tY}]\\
    =\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{\mathbf{i}tY}|X]]\\
    =\mathbb{E}[e^{\mathbf{i}tf(X)-\frac{1}{2}g(X)t^2}]$$

Now it is clear that if $f$ is linear and $g$ is constant then this reduces to the characteristic function of a normal distribution. But how would I go about proving that if $f,g$ are non-linear functions then this cannot be normal.